# Adding custom Exercise Environment blocks in reStructured Text

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

Is there an environment for formatting exercises? Something like

```
.. exercise:: Count to 10

   Write down all the numbers from 1 to (including 10)
```

I.e. this is for an instructional documentation that challenges the reader to work through the material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your custom semantics and style with `admonition`.

E.g. the example:

```
.. admonition:: description

        Here is some info for basic Plone troubleshooting, especially with add-on modules.
```

The resulting output will have `admonition-description` CSS class. Then you can then style with CSS, `:after` and `:before` pseudo-selectors e.g. if you want to add an exercise icon next to the text.

A random example file

- https://raw.github.com/collective/collective.developermanual/master/source/content/deleting.rst
- http://developer.plone.org/content/deleting.html